# Logon and Logoff scripts not running

Tags: windows, script, mysql, group-policy

I have set SQL queries to run on logon and logoff using group policy editor. But sometimes scripts do not run.

logon.bat

```
@echo off
echo INSERT INTO UPTIME(INTIME) VALUES(NOW()); > abc.sql
mysql --user=root --password=**** test < abc.sql
del abc.sql
```

logoff.bat

```
@echo off
echo SELECT MAX(ID) AS TEMP INTO @LAST_ENTRY FROM UPTIME; > abc.sql
echo UPDATE UPTIME SET OUTTIME = NOW() WHERE ID = @LAST_ENTRY; >> abc.sql
mysql --user=root --password=***** test < abc.sql
del abc.sql
```

I think MySQL engine might not be ready at the time of logon/logoff, How do I ensure that these scripts always executes.

Something like `if ready(MySQL) then execute`.

Comment: Are the scripts configured to run synchronously or asynchronously: this matters. Is `MySQL` Server installed locally? Runs [as a Microsoft Windows Service](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html)? Then something like `net start|findstr /I "mysql"` should raise `errorlevel 1` if not currently running...